# Copy file from Team Drive to My Drive - universal

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I am struggling with creating a script that will copy a file located on a Team Drive to My Drive for many users. I do not know how to implement a part to find My Drive of the user, it cannot be a static url address.

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var name = sheet.getName()
  var drive = ???
  var name = Browser.inputBox('Save File', 'Enter the name of the file', 
  Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  if (name != "cancel"){
    DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(name,drive);
  }
}
```

Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function saveAsSpreadsheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var name = sheet.getName()
  var name = Browser.inputBox('Save File', 'Enter the name of the file', 
  Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  if (name != "cancel"){
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFile(file);
  }
}
```

**P.S.**I am not changing the file handling logic here, I am only providing your answer to locate User's Local Drive assuming your sheet object will have file which needs to be saved.